# Handling too many HTTPRequest caused by image tag

Tags: java, jquery, mysql, apache

I am having an application which shows reports in tabular formate.

[image]

while rendering this report with more than 400 records each image tag is making a HTTPRequest to server causing server overhead.

Which causing performance issue. Due to this all other services are also getting affected.

### Tried Solution:

**Lazy loading:** fetch images only for onscreen records. still I have to make around 40 separate HTTPRequest's.

**Caching:**  huge data cannot catch.

Please suggest Something to optimize this. Thank you.

Comment: Lazy loading with caching seems like a very good solution to your problem.  What exactly did you try, and why did it fail?

Comment: suppose if one row contains around 4 image columns then the number of HTTPRequests will be 4x(number for records) this 'll again cause the same performance issue.

Comment: Then you should consider loading fewer images.  Can you restructure your UI to only load say 6 at a time?  Take a look at what some other sites are doing to give you an idea.

Comment: Thank you Tim, If I'll try to restrict it also, at least 200 images I have to load.

Comment: One way sites deal with this is to first show a thumbnail image, which is relatively small.  Rolling over or clicking would then trigger a download of the full image.

Answer (score 0):

Send the base64 encoded version of images as text and browser will render it if that is suitable for you.